# Is it possible to create multiple variables with the same name?

Tags: java, loops, android-studio

in an androidStudio lesson, i found this code:

```
for(int index = 0 ;index<10 ; index ++ ) {

    TextView wordView = new TextView(this);
    wordView.setText(words.get(index));
    rootView.addView(wordView);

}
```

we created 10 TextViews with the name wordView !!
and we added each TextView to the rootView !!
how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a given scope, you can only have one variable with a given name. A `for` loop has its own scope and only has **one** variable named `wordView`. Each time the loop iterates, it creates a new **instance** of the `TextView` class and assigns a reference to the variable `wordView`.

It is important to understand the difference between reference variables and class instances (or objects). You only have **one** variable named `wordView` here. You create **10** instances of `TextView`.

Comment: that means we can only access the last object created while the others still exists ?

Comment: @helmibenkhalifa Within the scope of the for loop, you can only access the most recently created `TextView` object. After the loop finishes, you no longer have direct access to **any** of them. Try adding `wordView.setText()` after the for loop and you will get a compiler error. All of the objects still exist because you add them to `rootView` which continues to manage the objects after the for loop finishes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept called scope.

The variable names are not conflicted in different scope.

In Java, each for loop block create a new scope. That means you create 10 different scope in your for loop, so 10 same variable name wordText works.